# Subset and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I have a problem to plot a subset of a data frame with ggplot2. My df is like:

```r
df = data.frame(ID = c('P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3', 'P3'),
                Value1 = c(100, 120, 300, 400, 130, 140),
                Value2 = c(12, 13, 11, 16, 15, 12))
```

How can I now plot `Value1` vs `Value2` only for `ID`s `'P1'` and `'P3'`?
For example I tried:

```r
ggplot(subset(df,ID=="P1 & P3") +
  geom_line(aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID)))
```

but I always receive an error.

Comment: `((ID =="P1") | (ID =="P3"))` might do the trick

Comment: Or `ID %in% c("P1", "P3")`.

Comment: @Hong and @ LostBrit I receive for both commands an error: Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'any'

Comment: Yes, it gives an error. Can you say a little bit about what are you trying to plot?

Comment: Data would be helpful.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here 2 options for subsetting:

Using `subset` from base R:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(subset(dat,ID %in% c("P1" , "P3"))) + 
         geom_line(aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID))
```

Using `subset` the argument of `geom_line`(Note I am using `plyr` package to use the special `.` function).

```
library(plyr)
ggplot(data=dat)+ 
  geom_line(aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID),
                ,subset = .(ID %in% c("P1" , "P3")))
```

You can also use the complementary subsetting:

```
subset(dat,ID != "P2")
```

Comment: It may be worth adding that following the depreciation of the `subset` argument the comparable results could be obtained using `geom_line(data=dat[dat$ID %in% c("P1" , "P3"),], ...)` as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34588455/1655567). In effect this works on the same basis as [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18165706/1655567) below. The minor difference is using subsetted data inside the geom call.

Comment: @agstudy @konrad-rudolph defining `data=function(x) {...}` may work in place of `subset`.

Comment: @agstudy My data frame contains 3 columns (Year, rain, temp). So, when I am trying to plot only for the selected year I used  `ggplot(subset(data=aggdata, Year %in% c("1901" , "1910")),
                                      aes(x=Year, y=tem, color=factor(Year)))` and it showing error `Error in Year %in% c("1901", "1910") : object 'Year' not found`. Could you tell me what I have to do?

Comment: is it possible to subset more than one column within ggplot? say I wanted to subset Year == 2022 & Age == 12 or something like that...with two columns to subset

Answer (score 29):

There's another solution that I find useful, especially when I want to plot multiple subsets of the same object:

```
myplot<-ggplot(df)+geom_line(aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID))
myplot %+% subset(df, ID %in% c("P1","P3"))
myplot %+% subset(df, ID %in% c("P2"))
```

Comment: @Nick Yes, your code is working fine (creating plot) but in my case not showing the line! Could you tell me what I have to do? [https://i.postimg.cc/85VgpMKz/Screenshot-from-2020-09-29-15-21-54.png]

Comment: You've specified Year as both grouping variable and colour. Lines are drawn between data points of the same group. Setting up the plot in this way means you have only one observation per group. So the solution is to remove "group=Year"

Comment: Anyway to ensure that this keep colours the same? i.e. there are four lines, red green blue purple, if you subset to keep item 1 and 4 to keep the colours as red and purple, rather than red and green.

Answer (score 16):

@agstudy's answer didn't work for me with the latest version of `ggplot2`, but this did, using `maggritr` pipes:

```
ggplot(data=dat)+ 
  geom_line(aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID),
                data = . %>% filter(ID %in% c("P1" , "P3")))
```

It works because if `geom_line` sees that `data` is a function, it will call that function with the inherited version of `data` and use the output of that function as `data`.

Comment: Does this still work? Not sure, whether they changed the `.` to `.x`. Haven't found anything in the NEWS though. See also my answer. BTW, they recently changed a lot.

Comment: @andschar Definitely still works. Both `.` and `.x` are fine.

Answer (score 14):

With option 2 in @agstudy's answer now deprecated, defining data with a function can be handy.

```
library(plyr)
ggplot(data=dat) + 
  geom_line(aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID),
            data=function(x){x$ID %in% c("P1", "P3"))
```

This approach comes in handy if you wish to reuse a dataset in the same plot, e.g. you don't want to specify a new column in the data.frame, or you want to explicitly plot one dataset in a layer above the other.:

```
library(plyr)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID)) + 
  geom_line(data=function(x){x[!x$ID %in% c("P1", "P3"), ]}, alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(data=function(x){x[x$ID %in% c("P1", "P3"), ]})
```

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2) 
l<-df[df$ID %in% c("P1","P3"),]
myplot<-ggplot(l)+geom_line(aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your formulation is almost correct. You want:

```
subset(dat, ID=="P1" | ID=="P3")
```

Where the `|` ('pipe') means 'or'. Your solution, `ID=="P1 & P3"`, is looking for a case where ID is literally `"P1 & P3"`

Answer (score 2):

Try filter to subset only the rows of P1 and P3

```
df2 <- filter(df, ID == "P1" | ID == "P3")
```

Than yo can plot Value1. vs Value2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `~subset(., ...)` - this is a way to do what Dave above suggests, which also

- works with current {ggplot2} (3.4.2)
- does not require the {magrittr} pipe - for those who switched to R pipe
- references the data as it was input to the data param of the `ggplot()` function, e.g. when the data was piped in
- is a bit more concise/easier to understand then defining a function

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ~subset(., cyl == 4), color = "red")
```

e.g. also works like so when the data was piped in:

```r
mtcars |> 
  filter(gear > 3) |> 
  ggplot(aes(hp, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ~subset(., cyl == 4), color = "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subset within ggplot

```
ggplot(data = subset(df, ID == "P1" | ID == "P2") +
   aes(Value1, Value2, group=ID, colour=ID) +
   geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @nicolaskruchten s answer you could do the following:

```r
require(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(ID = c('P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3', 'P3'),
                Value1 = c(100, 120, 300, 400, 130, 140),
                Value2 = c(12, 13, 11, 16, 15, 12))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(data = ~.x[.x$ID %in% c("P1" , "P3"), ],
            aes(Value1, Value2, group = ID, colour = ID))
```