# Modify Histogram to display only a fraction of total data

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I hope I have not overlooked an answer to this question:
I want to make with ggplot a histogramm of only a fraction of the total data. Here's my example:

```
df<-iris
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=..density..*100)) +
geom_bar(binwidth=0.1) +
ylab("percent")
```

This gives a histogramm of all lines.

Now I want to limit the data passed to the plot (for instance) to a Petal.Width of 0.2. Thus the histogram I wish for, only represents the ratio "count Petal.Width=0.2 divided by total count".

Thanks for helping a ggplot-rookie!! With base plot I managed to work around, but I failed here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to subset the data you're calling in the plot:

```
ggplot(data=df[df$Petal.Width == 0.2,], aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=..density..*100)) +
    geom_bar(binwidth=0.1) +
    ylab("percent")
```

Some other ways to subset data using ggplot are described in this post: [Subset and ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165578/subset-and-ggplot2)

Comment: Oh boy.. Of course! Thanks! I guess I was too much overloaded to see this solution..