# subset parameter in layers is no longer working with ggplot2 >= 2.0.0

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I updated to the newest version of `ggplot2` and run into problems by printing subsets in a layer.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(subset=.(x >= .5))
```

These lines of code worked in version `1.0.1` but not in `2.0.0`. It throws an error `Error: Unknown parameters: subset`.

I couldn't find an official change log or a way how to subset specific layers. Specially because this `plyr` solution was not very nice documented, I think I found it somewhere in stack overflow.

Comment: Probably not supported anymore, although I saw no mention of it in the change log. https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.0.0 There are lots of other ways to do this. Do you particularly need this way?

Comment: No, don't need this way, just found it very convenient... I am open for better or other solutions.

Comment: Yes it is depreciated - note the comment: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/34d0bd5d26a8929382d09606b4eda7a36ee20e5e/R/layer.r

Comment: Can I write it up and you accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the comments in the ggplot2 2.0.0 code:

```
#' @param subset DEPRECATED. An older way of subsetting the dataset used in a
#'   layer.
```

Which can be found here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/34d0bd5d26a8929382d09606b4eda7a36ee20e5e/R/layer.r

One way to do that now would be this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(data=df[df$x>=.5,])
```

or this, (but beware of "Non Standard Evaluation" (NSE) :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(data=subset(df,x>=.5))
```

I think this is the one considered most safe as it has no NSE or dollar-sign field selectors:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(data=df[df[["x"]]>=.5,])
```

But there are lots of others using pipes, etc...

Comment: Could give me some hints on other solution?! I always try to make my code lines as readable as possible and I always think these `df[df$x>.5,]` lines are a pain in the eye ;-) I loved the `subset` solution a lot.

Comment: I guess by using `subset(df, x > .5)` I will end up with almost the same as I had before and it is easier to read, isn't it?!

Comment: Oh, that is the one you happened upon anyway :)

Comment: Thanks. And an upvote would help me on my campaign for the `ggplot2`  bronze badge (47 upvotes to go) :)

Comment: ah, that was the deal?! ;-)

Comment: I added one more that does not use NSE which is apparently frowned upon.

Comment: Should be the same, but I would post it as a question I think. There are a lot of bugs in ggplot 2.0.0