# How to fix old ggplot2 code with subset parameter

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, ggtree

I want to run this code (below) to produce a gains/loss tree for some orthofinder data. I have been following a github guide
 https://github.com/guyleonard/orthomcl_tools

and have gotten through all of this except for the last part for plotting the data.

I'm sure there are a lot of ways you could do this in `ggplot2` but it would be really helpful if someone knows how to fix this code so that the subset parameter is no longer there.

This is the error message I get:

> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: subset
>           Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: subset
>           Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: subset
>           Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: subset
>           Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: subset
>           Warning message:
>           Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: size

I'm not sure yet if that aesthetics error is going to give me grief but I do know `R` no longer uses `subset` so that is definitely a problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtree)

user_report <- read.csv("outfile.phy_newstyle_report.txt", sep = "\t", header=TRUE, as.is=1, row.names=NULL)

user_tree <- read.tree("tree_4code_internal_labels.tree")

user_p <- ggplot(user_tree, aes(x, y), ladderize=TRUE) + geom_tree() + 
           theme_tree() + 
           geom_tiplab(size=3, align=TRUE, color="purple", x=13) + 
           xlab("") + ylab("") + 
           geom_text(aes(label=Gain, x=branch), size=3, color="springgreen4", vjust=-0.6, subset=.(!isTip)) + 
           geom_text(aes(label=Gain), size=3, color="springgreen4", hjust=0, subset=.(isTip), x=13.5) + 
           geom_text(aes(label=Loss, x=branch), size=3, color="firebrick3", vjust=1.3, subset=.(!isTip)) + 
           geom_text(aes(label=Loss), size=3, color="firebrick3", hjust=0, subset=.(isTip), x=14) + 
           geom_text(aes(label=node), size=2, hjust=-1.5, subset=.(!isTip), color="grey") + 
           scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.1, .2))

user_p <- user_p %<+% user_report

print(user_p)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588455/1222578

Comment: This answer that uses `.` and `filter` is also quite clever, and might work better when you have facetting in your plot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53264920/1222578