# Stata margins/marginsplot into R?

Tags: r, statistics, stata

I am trying to replicate a Stata marginsplot into `R`, but have not been able to do so, even after browsing StackExchange and trying to figure it out for a couple of weeks.

Do you happen to know how can I recreate a plot created using marginsplot in `R`?

First, I generated a reproducible dataset using the following `R` code:

```
set.seed(96)
sampleData <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:200,
    outcome = sample(1:7, 200, replace = T),
    scale = sample(1:7, 200, replace = T),
    dummy1 = sample(0:1, 200, replace = T),
    dummy2 = sample(0:1, 200, replace = T))
write.dta(dataframe, "sampledata.dta")
```

Then, I read the data into `Stata` and run the following commands to get the attached graph:

```
   reg outcome dummy1##c.scale dummy2##c.scale

   margins dummy1 dummy2, at(scale=(1(1)7))

   marginsplot, recast(line) name(outcome, replace)
```

Essentially, when this code is run in Stata I get the graph that I am trying to replicate in R:

[image]

Do you have any pointers that would help me replicate this graph?

Comment: It looks like a linear fit with a prediction interval maybe? I could probably have a crack at it but I don't know what the `reg outcome ....` line in stata is referring to exactly. What do the `##`'s mean?

Comment: @thelatemail it fits OLS regression with 'outcome' variable as outcome and explanatory variables being interaction of two binary variables with two continuous vairables.

Comment: @thelatemail The reg outcome ... line can be translated into R as follows: lm.out <- lm(outcome~dummy1*scale + dummy2*scale, data = sampleData)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# your data
set.seed(96)
sampleData <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:200,
    outcome = sample(1:7, 200, replace = T),
    scale = sample(1:7, 200, replace = T),
    dummy1 = sample(0:1, 200, replace = T),
    dummy2 = sample(0:1, 200, replace = T))

# all possible combinations
newData <- data.frame(scale=rep(1:7, each=4),
    dummy1=rep(c(0, 0, 1, 1), 7),
    dummy2=rep(0:1, 2*7))
newData$dummy <- paste(newData$dummy1, newData$dummy2)

a <- lm(outcome ~ dummy1*scale + dummy2*scale, data=sampleData)

b <- predict(a, newdata=newData, interval="confidence")

c <- cbind(newData, b)

require(ggplot2)

# one pane
d <- ggplot(c, aes(scale, fit, color=dummy)) 
d <- d + geom_line() 
# d <- d + facet_grid(dummy1 ~ dummy2)
d <- d + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), alpha=0.25)
d

# using facets
e <- ggplot(c, aes(scale, fit)) 
e <- e + geom_line() 
e <- e + facet_grid(dummy1 ~ dummy2)
e <- e + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), alpha=0.25)
e
```

I should include the plots.

[image: color]

[image: facet]

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! I think that ggplot2 is the way to go about this. But question... Why is the third graph the interaction between dummy1 and dummy2? I'm interested in the interaction between the variable scale and each dummy separately...

Comment: @EmilyB -- Sorry! I answered some other question! Is this just a predictions plot with confidence intervals? I have not used `margins` in Stata to get plots, only to get marginal effects at different combinations. But your plot is of levels of `outcome`. See if the above works.

Comment: The Stata code is just a prediction, so your code looks correct. Stata's margins command and narginsplot command only give marginal effects when used with the `, dydx()` option.

Comment: @RichardHerron I have another question related to this one... Is it possible to show three out of the four CIs in the plot that has only one pane? I got this code to work on my actual dataset, but realized I only want 3 out of the 4 CIs to show in the final graph... I can't figure out how to modify the geom_ribbon command to show only 3 out of the 4 CI. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EmilyB I would `subset` the data. This question/answer should give you all that you need. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18165730/334755