# Grayscale line graph and one line in red

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a grayscale line-graph with multiple groups (~10), but having one line `(spec=3)` that is in red.

See an example with only 3 groups below:

```
year <-c (2011, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2013)
x <- 1:10
cost <- sample(x, 9, replace=T)
spec <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))

dat <-data.frame(year=year, cost=cost, spec=spec)

# graph
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=year, y=cost, group=spec)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=spec)) + 
  **geom_line(group="3", col="red")** + 
  scale_colour_grey() + 
  theme_bw()
```

The problem is obviously with the `geom_line(group="3", col="red")` part, but I don't know how to fix it.

With this code I get something strange like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might do the trick, perhaps a bit of an overkill with the `melt` call, but should be really straightforward and is the most flexible approach, which also incorporates a comment made on another answer.
I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53264920/5795592 as the starting point. Should be flexible enough.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
melt(dat, measure.vars="cost", id.vars = c("year","spec") ) %>% ggplot(data=., aes(x=year, y=value)) +
    geom_line(aes(color=spec), data = . %>% subset(., spec %in% c("1","2"))) +
    geom_line(aes(color=spec), data = . %>% subset(., spec %in% c("3"))) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(gray.colors(2), 'red'))
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You only need to define `aes(color = )` once, then dial in you colors via a named custom color palette.

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=year, y=cost, group=spec)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=spec)) + 
  # geom_line(group="3", col="red") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "black", "2" = "grey", "3" = "red")) +
  # scale_colour_grey() +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: If you want a lot of grayscale colors and one red color you could customize the color scale something like this: `scale_color_manual(values = c(gray.colors(9), 'red'))`