# How do I remove an empty graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running some statistics in R. My data includes some columes of "yes/no" answers.
I would like to make a graph showing some of the findings but R keeps adding another graph (other than the yes/no). I suspect this is happening because I have some empty cells in the data table.
the code I'm using:

```
ggplot(data,mapping=aes(x=SmokeLife, y=Age))+geom_violin()
```

SmokeLife is a yes/no answer. Age is a continuous factor.
How do I remove the left hand graph from the pic below?
[image]

Comment: filter your data. E.g. use `dplyr::filter(data, SmokeLife %in% c('Yes','No'))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subset and ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165578/subset-and-ggplot2)