# ggplot2 how to combine line and boxplot time series with custom colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to overlay a line plot over a box plot with custom colors.

I feel almost certain that I've done this before, but I can't find a solution right now. Any takers on this question? Thanks in advance.

## The box plot

This code:

```
  ggplot(plotdata) +
    geom_boxplot(data=resp_daily_ca_ranked,
                 aes(x=as.factor(week), y=pct, fill = rankgroup)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=COLS) +
    # NOT RUN: geom_line(aes(week, pct, colour=Group)) +
    theme_minimal() + xlab("") + ylab(YLAB) +
    scale_color_manual(values=COLS) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    ggtitle(label = TITLE, subtitle = SUBTITLE)
```

produces the desired boxplot:
[image: boxplot_alone]

## The line plot

This code:

```
  ggplot(plotdata) +
    # NOT RUN: geom_boxplot(data=resp_daily_ca_ranked,
    # NOT RUN:              aes(x=as.factor(week), y=pct, fill = rankgroup)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=COLS) +
    geom_line(aes(week, pct, colour=Group)) +
    theme_minimal() + xlab("") + ylab(YLAB) +
    scale_color_manual(values=COLS) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    ggtitle(label = TITLE, subtitle = SUBTITLE)
```

produces the desired line plot:

[image: line_plot_alone]

## The error

However this code, with the desired components:

```
  ggplot(plotdata) +
    geom_boxplot(data=resp_daily_ca_ranked,
                 aes(x=as.factor(week), y=pct, fill = rankgroup)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=COLS) +
    geom_line(aes(week, pct, colour=Group)) +
    theme_minimal() + xlab("") + ylab(YLAB) +
    scale_color_manual(values=COLS) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    ggtitle(label = TITLE, subtitle = SUBTITLE)
```

produces this error:

```
Error: `mapped_discrete` objects can only be created from numeric vectors
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

## The naive approach

This code:

```
ggplot(plotdata) +
  geom_boxplot(data=resp_daily_ca_ranked,
               aes(x=week, y=pct, fill = rankgroup)) + # <-- removed factor
  scale_fill_manual(values=COLS) +
  geom_line(aes(week, pct, colour=Group)) +
  theme_minimal() + xlab("") + ylab(YLAB) +
  scale_color_manual(values=COLS) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  ggtitle(label = TITLE, subtitle = SUBTITLE)
```

Produces this plot (which is not desired)

[image: not_what_I_want_at_all]

## Code to create example:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

plotdata <- structure(
  list(structure(
    c(18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 
      18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18376L, 
      18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 
      18383L, 18383L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18397L, 18397L, 
      18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 
      18404L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 
      18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 
      18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 
      18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18453L, 
      18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 
      18460L, 18460L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L),
    class = c('IDate', 'Date')),
    c(0.1649, 0.1571, 0.1402, 0.1288, 0.1179, 0.1011, 0.0826, 0.0465, 0.0435, 0.0401, 0.0388, 
      0.0363, 0.0334, 0.0288, 0.0282, 0.0263, 0.0266, 0.0251, 0.0229, 0.0224, 0.0186, 0.0431, 
      0.0322, 0.0325, 0.0253, 0.025, 0.0214, 0.0155, 0.0453, 0.0301, 0.0322, 0.0233, 0.0238, 
      0.0189, 0.0149, 0.026, 0.0218, 0.0231, 0.0189, 0.0188, 0.019, 0.0163, 0.0126, 0.0121, 
      0.013, 0.0119, 0.0109, 0.015, 0.0138, 0.007, 0.0071, 0.0073, 0.0066, 0.0068, 0.0074, 
      0.0069, 0.0045, 0.0049, 0.0051, 0.0047, 0.0048, 0.0048, 0.0046, 0.0039, 0.0039, 0.0042, 
      0.0039, 0.0036, 0.0034, 0.0031, 0.0035, 0.0033, 0.0031, 0.0033, 0.0031, 0.0036, 0.0032, 
      0.0025, 0.003, 0.0028, 0.0031, 0.0031, 0.0029, 0.0027, 0.0023, 0.0025, 0.0023, 0.0026, 
      0.0024, 0.0028, 0.0025, 0.002, 0.0021, 0.0021, 0.002, 0.0024, 0.0027, 0.003, 0.0017, 
      0.0019, 0.0023, 0.0022, 0.0022, 0.0022, 0.0023, 0.0025, 0.0026, 0.0026, 0.0025, 
      0.0024, 0.0023, 0.0024, 0.0027, 0.0032, 0.0029, 0.0028, 0.0024, 0.0034, 0.0033),
    c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', 
      '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', 
      '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 
      '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', 
      '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', 
      '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 
      '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 
      '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')),
  .Names = c('week', 'pct', 'Group'),
  row.names = c(NA, -119L),
  class = c('data.table', 'data.frame'))
resp_daily_ca_ranked <- structure(list(structure(
  c(18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 
    18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 
    18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 
    18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 
    18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 
    18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 
    18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 
    18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 
    18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 
    18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 
    18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 
    18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 
    18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 
    18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 
    18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 
    18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 
    18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 
    18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 
    18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 
    18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 
    18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 
    18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 
    18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 
    18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 
    18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 
    18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L, 18355L, 18355L, 18355L, 18362L, 18362L, 18362L, 
    18369L, 18369L, 18369L, 18376L, 18376L, 18376L, 18383L, 18383L, 18383L, 18390L, 18390L, 18390L, 
    18397L, 18397L, 18397L, 18404L, 18404L, 18404L, 18411L, 18411L, 18411L, 18418L, 18418L, 18418L, 
    18425L, 18425L, 18425L, 18432L, 18432L, 18432L, 18439L, 18439L, 18439L, 18446L, 18446L, 18446L, 
    18453L, 18453L, 18453L, 18460L, 18460L, 18460L, 18467L, 18467L, 18467L),
  class = c('IDate', 'Date')),
  c('4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', 
    '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', 
    '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', 
    '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', 
    '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', 
    '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
    '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
    '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
    '1', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', 
    '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', 
    '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', 
    '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', 
    '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', 
    '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', 
    '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', 
    '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', 
    '3', '3', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', 
    '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', 
    '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7'),
  c(0.1277, 0.1051, 0.1096, 0.0341, 0.0329, 0.0382, 0.031, 0.0184, 0.0176, 0.0392, 0.022, 0.0124, 
    0.0306, 0.0186, 0.0077, 0.0188, 0.0228, 0.0197, 0.0087, 0.0157, 0.0181, 0.0063, 0.0055, 0.0082,
    0.0037, 0.0051, 0.0055, 0.004, 0.0025, 0.0043, 0.0023, 0.0024, 0.0046, 0.0022, 0.0029, 0.0038,
    0.0027, 0.0024, 0.0028, 0.0024, 0.0028, 0.002, 0.0025, 0.002, 0.0019, 0.0023, 0.0015, 0.0016, 
    0.0027, 0.0036, 0.0028, 0.1271, 0.1181, 0.1218, 0.04, 0.0398, 0.0353, 0.0384, 0.0244, 0.0168, 
    0.0249, 0.0251, 0.0333, 0.0185, 0.034, 0.0263, 0.0254, 0.0213, 0.0191, 0.0186, 0.0095, 0.0107,
    0.0064, 0.0066, 0.0048, 0.0051, 0.0047, 0.0055, 0.0044, 0.0029, 0.0035, 0.0025, 0.0024, 0.0025,
    0.0037, 0.0022, 0.0022, 0.0041, 0.0031, 0.0016, 0.0026, 0.0025, 0.0029, 0.004, 0.002, 0.0016, 
    0.0037, 0.0037, 0.0015, 0.0031, 0.0024, 0.0029, 0.1671, 0.1859, 0.1612, 0.0471, 0.0549, 0.043,
    0.0367, 0.0315, 0.0299, 0.0444, 0.0269, 0.047, 0.0355, 0.0448, 0.0518, 0.0237, 0.0251, 0.0275, 
    0.0144, 0.0126, 0.0128, 0.0073, 0.0084, 0.0071, 0.005, 0.0065, 0.004, 0.005, 0.0046, 0.0036, 
    0.005, 0.0057, 0.003, 0.003, 0.0022, 0.002, 0.0022, 0.0028, 0.002, 0.0025, 0.0026, 0.0014,
    0.0021, 0.0029, 0.0011, 0.0031, 0.0037, 0.0016, 0.0038, 0.0035, 0.0023, 0.1047, 0.1079, 0.09, 
    0.0332, 0.0354, 0.0328, 0.0195, 0.0345, 0.0282, 0.016, 0.0333, 0.0343, 0.012, 0.0362, 0.0275, 
    0.0189, 0.0205, 0.0195, 0.016, 0.0124, 0.0116, 0.0073, 0.0064, 0.0063, 0.0044, 0.0052, 0.0046, 
    0.0037, 0.0037, 0.0032, 0.0039, 0.0039, 0.0032, 0.0021, 0.0033, 0.0033, 0.0029, 0.0033, 0.0032, 
    0.0026, 0.0023, 0.0028, 0.002, 0.0023, 0.0023, 0.0021, 0.0031, 0.0028, 0.0031, 0.0039, 0.0034, 
    0.1311, 0.1591, 0.1527, 0.0482, 0.0451, 0.0413, 0.0219, 0.0258, 0.0286, 0.014, 0.0223, 0.0631, 
    0.0132, 0.0178, 0.0395, 0.0198, 0.0209, 0.0202, 0.0186, 0.0197, 0.0099, 0.0093, 0.0103, 0.0052, 
    0.0061, 0.0065, 0.0038, 0.005, 0.0048, 0.0026, 0.005, 0.0059, 0.0028, 0.0054, 0.0031, 0.0026, 
    0.003, 0.0034, 0.0015, 0.0034, 0.0024, 0.0028, 0.0027, 0.0026, 0.0016, 0.0036, 0.0021, 0.0026, 
    0.0031, 0.0028, 0.0029, 0.1301, 0.1439, 0.1352, 0.0382, 0.0416, 0.0413, 0.0406, 0.0197, 0.028,
    0.0303, 0.0241, 0.0339, 0.0219, 0.0281, 0.0365, 0.024, 0.0207, 0.0223, 0.02, 0.024, 0.0121, 
    0.0092, 0.0094, 0.0064, 0.0072, 0.0051, 0.0054, 0.0034, 0.0026, 0.0035, 0.0023, 0.002, 0.0024, 
    0.0032, 0.0024, 0.0032, 0.0028, 0, 0.0013, 0.0038, 0.001, 0.0025, 0.0016, 0.002, 0.0024, 0.0024,
    0.001, 0.0022, 0.003, 0.004, 0.0037, 0.0668, 0.0612, 0.0969, 0.0247, 0.032, 0.034, 0.0135, 
    0.0109, 0.0208, 0.0059, 0.007, 0.0173, 0.0062, 0.0046, 0.0185, 0.0119, 0.0196, 0.0182, 0.0125, 
    0.021, 0.0151, 0.0062, 0.0066, 0.0072, 0.0043, 0.007, 0.0053, 0.0018, 0.005, 0.0028, 0.003, 
    0.0031, 0.0032, 0.0023, 0.0014, 0.0032, 0.002, 0.001, 0.0027, 0.0031, 0.0014, 0.0028, 0.0019,
    0.0013, 0.0021, 0.0012, 0, 0.0033, 0.0024, 0.003, 0.0034)),
  row.names = c(NA, -357L),
  class = c('data.table', 'data.frame'),
  .Names = c('week', 'rankgroup', 'pct'))


TITLE <- "Incremental Response Rate by Community Area (grouped)"
SUBTITLE <- sprintf("Weeks ending %s to %s",
                    format(min(plotdata$week), "%m/%d/%y"), 
                    format(max(plotdata$week), "%m/%d/%y"))
YLAB <- "Incremental Percent Responding"
COLS <- structure(c('#F3771AFF', '#D84C3EFF', '#AE305CFF', '#7F1E6CFF', '#500E6CFF', 
                    '#1E0C44FF', '#000004FF'),
                  .Names = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is pratically the same as the question's code. Perhaps the main difference is to explicitly assign the `data` argument in the layers `boxplot` and `line`.

```
ggplot(plotdata) +
  geom_boxplot(data = resp_daily_ca_ranked,
               mapping = aes(week, pct, fill = rankgroup)) +
  geom_line(data = plotdata, 
            mapping = aes(week, pct, color = Group), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = COLS) +
  scale_color_manual(values = COLS) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab("") + ylab(YLAB) +
  ggtitle(label = TITLE, subtitle = SUBTITLE) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I did in the "naive" approach. I'm looking for the box plots broken up by group within the time period.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer today.

Frist, I needed to remember that `aes` requires a "group" argument (and I literally mean remember because only x and y are documented inputs for aes).

Second it's necessary to use `interaction` within boxplot to capture the time and group.

Third, I also combined the grouped and ungrouped data, then subset the data within the geom calls. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165578/subset-and-ggplot2)

```
combodata <- rbind(plotdata[,list(week, pct, Group, subset="line")],
                   resp_daily_ca_ranked[ , list(week, pct, Group=rankgroup,
                                                subset="boxplot")])
ggplot(combodata, aes(x=week, y=pct, fill=Group)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=interaction(week, Group)),
               data = function(x){x[subset=="boxplot"]})+
  geom_line(aes(color=Group), data = function(x){x[subset=="line"]}) +
  theme_minimal() + xlab("") + ylab(YLAB) +
  scale_color_manual(values=COLS) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=COLS) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  ggtitle(label = TITLE, subtitle = SUBTITLE)
```

I'm not sure if it was necessary to combine the data, but it's nice anyway because of the way I'm going to handle the data.

[image]

And, by the way, the reason for all this is to find out if there are meaningful deviations within the aggregated data.

Looking at this one time period for example:
[image]

Is interesting... why did one of the lowest performers have a spike? Is it related to anything else? This gives me a sense of where to look in the data.